# SSRS Reporting - count number of group rows

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I am trying to the count of number of groups in my report I know I could do it in the SQL however trying to avoid adding redundant data to my dataset if I can.

I have a MainDataSet that could have multiple entries per distinct group item. All I want is the no. of groups not the count of items within the group.

For example words starting with alphabet letters, lets say I have 2 groups A and B only (NB: number of groups can change dynamically as I filter the MainDataSet based on user parameter selection):

```
Group | Data
------|-----
    A | Apple
    A | Ant
    B | Balloon
    B | Book
    B | Bowl
```

Final Result:

```
Group | Index | NGroups
    A |   1   | 2
    B |   2   | 2
```

I know I can get the Index using a aggregate function as follows:

```
RunningValue(Fields!Group.Value, CountDistinct, "TablixName")
```

But how do I get the NGroups value?
I guess I could also create another dataset based on the MainDataSet (make use of a sql function) and do:

```
SELECT 'X' AS GroupCount, COUNT(Distinct Group) AS NGroups
FROM dbo.udf_MainDataSet() 
WHERE FieldX = @Parameter1
```

Then use a LookUp:

```
Lookup("X", Fields!GroupCount.Value, Fields!NGroups.Value, "NewDataSet")
```

But is there a simple solution that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

CountDistinct(Fields!Group.Value, "TablixName")